# Python, rasing an exception without arguments

Tags: python, exception, arguments, raise

I would like to know the best practice about raising an exception without arguments.
In the official python documentation, you can see this :

```
try:
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
```

(http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html chap. 8.6)

and in some differents code, like Django or Google code, you can see this :

```
  def AuthenticateAndRun(self, username, password, args):
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

(http://code.google.com/p/neatx/source/browse/trunk/neatx/lib/auth.py)

The exception is instanciate before being raised while there is no argument.
What is the purpose to instanciate an exception without arguments ? When I should use the first case or the second case ?

Thanks in advance
Fabien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising an exception class instead of an exception instance is deprecated syntax and should not be used in new code.

```
raise Exception, "This is not how to raise an exception..."
```

Comment: For those curious, see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#transition-plan for more info about exception-related deprecation.

Comment: I'm not able to figure out what you're recommending.  Your code example seems to be what **not** to do.  Perhaps you should show what *should* be done.

Answer (score 5):

You can use whichever form you like. There is no real difference and both are legal in Python 2 and 3. [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) does not specify which one is recommended.

---

A little more information on the "class form" support:

```
try:
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
```

This form is perfectly legal in both Python 2 and 3.
Excerpt from [pep-3109](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3109/):

> raise EXCEPTION is used to raise a new exception. This form has two
>   sub-variants: EXCEPTION may be an exception class or an instance of an
>   exception class; valid exception classes are BaseException and its
>   subclasses [5]. **If EXCEPTION is a subclass, it will be called with no
>   arguments to obtain an exception instance.**

It is also described in [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement):

> ... If it is a class, the exception instance will be obtained when needed
>   by instantiating the class with no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In languages like C++ you can raise any object, not just Exceptions. Python is more constrained. If you try :

```
raise 1
```

You get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not int
```

In python programming model you can usually use a class by itself instead of an instance (this is handy for fast creation of unique instances, just define a class). Hence no wonder you can raise an exception class instead of an exception instance.

However like Ignacio said, that is deprecated.

Also, some side-note that is not the direct question:

You could also see raise alone by itself in some code. Without any object class or anything. It is used in exception handlers to re-raise the current exception and will keep the initial traceback.